# A integral computation problem

Tags: integration

For $a,b \geq 0$, integrate
$$\int_0^\infty \dfrac{x^\frac{1}{a}}{b}e^{-x} dx. $$

I came across this integral and I have no idea where to begin.

Comment: Well, the $b$ just comes out.  The rest looks a lot like the [Gamma function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice that if we let $\alpha=\frac1a$ your integral is:
$$I=\frac1b\int_0^\infty x^\alpha e^{-x}dx$$
and the Gamma function is defined as:
$$\Gamma(z)=\int_0^\infty x^{z-1}e^{-x}dx$$
and so:
$$I=\frac1b\Gamma(\alpha+1)=\frac1b\Gamma\left(1+\frac1a\right)$$